# Bootstrap changing keyboard tab key behavior to horizontal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Due to the boot strap design, the keyboard tab key is working vertically(col wise) instead of horizontally.

Can I make the keyboard tab key behavior horizontal(default behavior) without changing the design

This is the section of code.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <span class="col-md-6">
            <select ng-model="typeId" required=""><option value="" class="" selected="selected">--SELECT--</option>
                <option label="Employment" value="number:2">Employment</option>
                <option label="Female" value="number:3">Female</option>
                <option label="Food" value="number:4">Food</option>
                <option label="Male" value="number:1">Male</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12" ">
        <span class="col-md-6">
             <input type="text" name="nameAr" required="" ng-maxlength="250">
        </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <span class="col-md-6">
            <select ng-model="nId" ng-options="non.nId as non.nlity for non in List" ng-invalid-required" name="nationality" id="nationality" required="">
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-6" for="profession">Profession:</label>
            <span class="col-md-6">
                <select ng-model="rpationId" ng-options="ocp.rpationId as ocp.occupation for ocp in occupationList" >\
                </select>
            </span>
        </span>
   </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="form-group col-md-12" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : regCtrl.userForm.mmpId.$invalid &amp;&amp; regCtrl.userForm.mmpId.$dirty }">
          <label class="col-md-6" for="mmpId">MMP Id: *</label> 
                <span class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" name="mmpId" class="form-control ">
                </span> 
                 <div class="col-sm-6 error-color ng-scope ng-active" >
                        <span ng-message="required" class="ng-scope">This field is required</span>
                </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12" >
         <label class="col-md-6" for="name">Name: *</label> 
              <span class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" name="name" ng-maxlength="250">
                </span> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12" >
        <label class="col-md-6" for="dob">Date of Birth: *</label> 
            <span class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="date" name="dob"   ng-maxlength="11">
                        </span> 

    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12" ng-class="">
         <label class="col-md-6" for="contactNo">Contact No: *</label> 
                <span class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="number" name="contactNo" required="">
                </span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you talking about keyboard tab key behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried tabindex ? Specify the values for it starting from 1 to form elements in the order you want.

Comment: Is there any other option other than tabInex, yes it works. But have to give for each element

Comment: Browsers follow the natural parent/child order of the DOM when deciding where the focus should go next. So you have to either use tab index or start writing a bunch of javascript to make the focus go where you want. Another approach would be to ditch the bootstrap columns and use something like flexbox to layout the elements so that the natural order of the DOM matches your desired tab order.

Comment: @user630209 I have added the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of your grouping of the form elements. You are grouping the elements column wise hence the tab works column wise.

You have grouped 4 form elements in first col-md-4 and the next 4 in the second col-md-4 so default tab control will first cover first col-md-4 elements and then the next col-md-4 elements.
Either use tabindex or change your layout to row wise as below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="nameAr" required="" ng-maxlength="250">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="nameAr" required="" ng-maxlength="250">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="nameAr" required="" ng-maxlength="250">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="nameAr" required="" ng-maxlength="250">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="nameAr" required="" ng-maxlength="250">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="nameAr" required="" ng-maxlength="250">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Displays the whole field in row wise.

Comment: You need to divide your form elements in multiple rows. Can you create a fiddle/plnkr of what you have done? Will correct it.

Comment: new to jsfiddle not able to add those css

Comment: I have made the changes to sponsors detail form. Refer http://plnkr.co/edit/leeK7iyCck845Go9bWRZ?p=preview. Widen the preview window and you will notice 3 form fields in a row and horizontal tab working. You can do rest of the changes similar to it.